# Jenkins gives POM file pom.xml specified the -f/--file command-line argument does not exist""

Tags: maven, jenkins, github, continuous-integration, testng

Actually i am integrating my TestNG and rest-assured tests with jenkins every thing  is integrated well by when i take build it gets failed below is the issue i got in console out put:

Building in workspace C:\Users\True Meridian.jenkins\workspace\ApiAutomation

> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
>   Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
>   C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/Usmanch760/PlayPalApi.git # timeout=10
>   Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/Usmanch760/PlayPalApi.git
>   C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
>   C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/Usmanch760/PlayPalApi.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=30
>   C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
>   C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
>   Checking out Revision 1831aa5e76106af1bf98cb25aa31ae46f360e5df (refs/remotes/origin/master)
>   C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
>   C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe checkout -f 1831aa5e76106af1bf98cb25aa31ae46f360e5df
>   Commit message: "Pom updated TestNg.xml"
>   C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-list --no-walk 1831aa5e76106af1bf98cb25aa31ae46f360e5df # timeout=10
>   Unpacking https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.5.3/apache-maven-3.5.3-bin.zip to C:\Users\True Meridian.jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\MAVEN_HOME on Jenkins
>   [ApiAutomation] $ cmd.exe /C '""C:\Users\True Meridian.jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\MAVEN_HOME\bin\mvn.cmd"' -f pom.xml clean install && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
>   POM file pom.xml specified the -f/--file command-line argument does not exist 
>   Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
>   TestNG Reports Processing: START
>   Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: **/testng-results.xml
>   testng-results.xml was last modified before this build started. Ignoring it.
>   Saving reports...
>   Found matching files but did not find any TestNG results.
>   Finished: FAILURE

Note: testNG test working fine on my ecclipse

here is my pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.Test.automation</groupId>
  <artifactId>PlayPalApi</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>PlayPalApi</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>





        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
         <!--   <scope>compile</scope> -->
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.restassured/rest-assured -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.10</version>
            <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20170516</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.relevantcodes/extentreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>2.41.2</version>
        </dependency>

          </dependencies>


        <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>

                    <!-- Old design where we can hard code TestNG suite in pom.xml -->
                     <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>

                    </suiteXmlFiles> 

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>







</project>
```

Any help would really appreciated thanks.

Comment: is testng.xml file available on same directory as pom.xml?

Comment: thanks for the reply murali , yes its on same directory

Comment: try providing path of pom.xml in -f command.